# What is the meaning of "validation_data will override validation_split." in keras model.fit documentation

Tags: python, keras

I am new to python and machine learning. I have a confusion in the sentence in keras model.fiit that is "validation_data will override validation_split." Does that mean if I give validation data like this

```
history = model.fit(X_train, [train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode],validation_data= (y_train,[test_labels_hotEncode,test_labels_hotEncode,test_labels_hotEncode]),train_labels_hotEncode]), validation_split=0.3 ,epochs=epochs, batch_size= 64, callbacks=[lr_sc])
```

The validation split will not be accepted? And the function will only use Validation_data instead of split?

Also, I am trying to test my data on 30% of training data.

But if I try to use `model.fit` with only validation_split = 0.3 the validation accuracy gets really ugly. I am using inception googleNet architecture for this.

```
loss: 1.8204 - output_loss: 1.1435 - auxilliary_output_1_loss: 1.1292 - auxilliary_output_2_loss: 1.1272 - output_acc: 0.3845 - auxilliary_output_1_acc: 0.3797 - auxilliary_output_2_acc: 0.3824 - val_loss: 9.7972 - val_output_loss: 6.6655 - val_auxilliary_output_1_loss: 5.0973 - val_auxilliary_output_2_loss: 5.3417 - val_output_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_auxilliary_output_1_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_auxilliary_output_2_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

**CODE GOOGLENET**

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(224,224,3))

image = Conv2D(64,(7,7),padding='same', strides=(2,2), activation='relu', name='conv_1_7x7/2', kernel_initializer=kernel_init, bias_initializer=bias_init)(input_layer)

image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_1_3x3/2')(image)
image = Conv2D(64, (1,1), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv_2a_3x3/1' )(image)
image = Conv2D(192, (3,3), padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu', name='conv_2b_3x3/1')(image)
image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_2_3x3/2')(image)

image = inception_module(image,
                    filters_1x1= 64,
                    filters_3x3_reduce= 96,
                    filter_3x3 = 128,
                    filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                    filters_5x5= 32,
                    filters_pool_proj=32,
                    name='inception_3a')

image = inception_module(image,
                            filters_1x1=128,
                            filters_3x3_reduce=128,
                            filter_3x3=192,
                            filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                            filters_5x5=96,
                            filters_pool_proj=64,
                            name='inception_3b')

image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_3_3x3/2')(image)

image = inception_module(image, 
                            filters_1x1=192,
                            filters_3x3_reduce=96,
                            filter_3x3=208,
                            filters_5x5_reduce=16,
                            filters_5x5=48,
                            filters_pool_proj=64,
                            name='inception_4a')

image1 = AveragePooling2D((5,5), strides=3)(image)
image1 = Conv2D(128, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(image1)
image1 = Flatten()(image1)
image1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(image1)
image1 = Dropout(0.4)(image1)
image1 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_1')(image1)

image = inception_module(image,
                            filters_1x1 = 160,
                            filters_3x3_reduce= 112,
                            filter_3x3= 224,
                            filters_5x5_reduce= 24,
                            filters_5x5= 64,
                            filters_pool_proj=64,
                            name='inception_4b')

image = inception_module(image,
                           filters_1x1= 128,
                           filters_3x3_reduce = 128,
                           filter_3x3= 256,
                           filters_5x5_reduce= 24,
                           filters_5x5=64,
                           filters_pool_proj=64,
                           name='inception_4c')

image = inception_module(image,
                           filters_1x1=112,
                           filters_3x3_reduce=144,
                           filter_3x3= 288,
                           filters_5x5_reduce= 32,
                           filters_5x5=64,
                           filters_pool_proj=64,
                           name='inception_4d')

image2 = AveragePooling2D((5,5), strides=3)(image)
image2 = Conv2D(128, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(image2)
image2 = Flatten()(image2)
image2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(image2)
image2 = Dropout(0.4)(image2) #Changed from 0.7
image2 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='auxilliary_output_2')(image2)

image = inception_module(image,
                            filters_1x1=256,
                            filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                            filter_3x3=320,
                            filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                            filters_5x5=128,
                            filters_pool_proj=128,
                            name= 'inception_4e')

image = MaxPool2D((3,3), padding='same', strides=(2,2), name='max_pool_4_3x3/2')(image)

image = inception_module(image,
                           filters_1x1=256,
                           filters_3x3_reduce=160,
                           filter_3x3= 320,
                           filters_5x5_reduce=32,
                           filters_5x5= 128,
                           filters_pool_proj=128,
                           name='inception_5a')

image = inception_module(image, 
                           filters_1x1=384,
                           filters_3x3_reduce=192,
                           filter_3x3=384,
                           filters_5x5_reduce=48,
                           filters_5x5=128,
                           filters_pool_proj=128,
                           name='inception_5b')

image = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool_5_3x3/1')(image)

image = Dropout(0.4)(image)
image = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='output')(image)

model = Model(input_layer, [image,image1,image2], name='inception_v1')

model.summary()


epochs = 2
initial_lrate = 0.01 # Changed From 0.01

def decay(epoch, steps=100):
  initial_lrate = 0.01
  drop = 0.96
  epochs_drop = 8
  lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop,math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))#
  return lrate

sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
# nadam = keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr= 0.002, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None)
# keras
lr_sc = LearningRateScheduler(decay)
# rms = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr = initial_lrate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
# ad = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=initial_lrate)
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'],loss_weights=[1,0.3,0.3], optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

# loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'

history = model.fit(X_train, [train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode,train_labels_hotEncode], validation_split=0.3 ,epochs=epochs, batch_size= 32, callbacks=[lr_sc])
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validation_split` is a parameter that gets passed in. It's a number that determines how your data should be partitioned into training and validation sets. For example if `validation_split = 0.1` then 10% of your data will be used in the validation set and 90% of your data will be used in the test set.

`validation_data` is a parameter where you explicitly pass in the validation set. If you pass in validation data, `keras` uses your explicitly passed in data instead of computing the validation set using `validation_split`. This is what it means by "ignore" - passing in an argument for `validation_data` overrides whatever you pass in for `validation_split`.

In your situation since you want to use 30% of your data as validation data, simply pass in `validation_split=0.3` and don't pass in an argument for `validation_data`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. But I am facing another problem if I dont give `validation_data`, and only apply `validation_split`, the accuracy gets really ugly like.
`loss: 1.9336 - output_loss: 1.2280 - auxilliary_output_1_loss: 1.1791 - auxilliary_output_2_loss: 1.1731 - output_acc: 0.3574 - auxilliary_output_1_acc: 0.3708 - auxilliary_output_2_acc: 0.3642 - val_loss: 9.3849 - val_output_loss: 6.3216 - val_auxilliary_output_1_loss: 5.0935 - val_auxilliary_output_2_loss: 5.1177 - val_output_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_auxilliary_output_1_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_auxilliary_output_2_acc: 0.0000e+00`

Comment: Can you tell me why?

Comment: @FarukhKhan what you have asked is a separate question. That issue is probably related to your model architecture and not the validation split. You will need to post more information about your model.

Comment: @FarukhKhan `validation_split` draws from the last samples. Try shuffling your data.